# Whats the risk of using TPL with ConcurrentDictionary with "addValueFactory"? MSDN implies threading issues

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

[MSDN says the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675.aspx) about addValueFactory in a multi threaded environment:

> **Remarks**
>
> If you call AddOrUpdate simultaneously on different threads, addValueFactory may be called multiple times, but its
>   key/value pair might not be added to the dictionary for every call.

[There is a closed connect issue on this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/693563/concurrentdictionary-tkey-tvalue-addorupdate-tkey-func-tkey-tvalue-func-tkey-tvalue-tvalue), but nothing seems to have been done.  When I read the above excerpt I **guess** that one of these things *might* be happening:

1. The Update() method is called continuously until it succeeds (could turn into slowness/contention that should be avoided under high load.)
2. The update is discarded, and the application thinks it succeeded. (corruption)
3. The data is updated on the thread local copy of the variable, and not the other threads.  (This might be a stretch, but since it's not documented anything might be happening)

Can anyone explain what that sentence means?

---

**Part 2**

@Douglas shared code which I modified.  It is interesting to see how many times each "Add" was called vs each "update".  The output is interesting because only one return value has an "add" value in it.  All others are "updated" despite Add being called multiple times.

I want to somehow prevent the update method from being called at all.

```
        ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> numbers = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
        Parallel.For(0, 30, x =>
        {
           var returned = numbers.AddOrUpdate(1,
                i =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("addValueFactory has been called");
                    return i.ToString() + "AAA" + x;
                },
                (i, s) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("updateValueFactory has been called");
                    return i.ToString() + "u" + x;
                });

           Console.WriteLine(returned);
        });
```

*output*

```
addValueFactory has been called
addValueFactory has been called
addValueFactory has been called
addValueFactory has been called
addValueFactory has been called
addValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
addValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
addValueFactory has been called
1u15
updateValueFactory has been called
addValueFactory has been called
1u24
updateValueFactory has been called
1u25
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1AAA0
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u26
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u18
updateValueFactory has been called
1u19
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u21
1u20
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u22
updateValueFactory has been called
1u16
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u1
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u3
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u4
1u2
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u6
1u27
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u23
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u9
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u10
updateValueFactory has been called
1u12
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u17
1u7
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u28
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u11
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u8
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u5
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
1u29
1u13
updateValueFactory has been called
1u14
```

Answer (score 3):

In practice, the only thing it means is that your `addValueFactory` method should be thread-safe *and* idempotent, meaning that it won't give incorrect results if it is called multiple times (possibly concurrently) for the same value.

Consider the following contrived example:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> numbers = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
Parallel.For(0, 10, x =>
{
    numbers.AddOrUpdate(1,
        i =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("addValueFactory has been called");
            return i.ToString();
        },
        (i, s) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("updateValueFactory has been called");
            return i.ToString();
        });
});
```

If the `AddOrUpdate` method was perfectly synchronized, then you would expect the output to record a single `addValueFactory` call, followed by nine `updateValueFactory` calls. However, due to the mentioned clause, you may get multiple `addValueFactory` calls instead.

```
addValueFactory has been called
addValueFactory has been called
addValueFactory has been called
addValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
updateValueFactory has been called
```

In the majority of cases, this is a benign race condition, particularly since most `addValueFactory` delegates would not need to alter any state.

Comment: I'm thinking of using concurrentDictionary to ensure that only one instance of "work" gets done among many threads.  It appears in this case I might have 4 (or more) instances running.  With this question in mind, [would you assist with this question which includes my use case?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13445505/328397)